# Create resource file(.resx) on the click event of button in windows form

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, resx

I have a Windows form on that a button named "Create Resource" and a text box which takes the value of the file where i want to save the resource file.

Please help in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ResXResourceWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter(v=vs.110).aspx) (in System.Resources namespace).

It's quite straightforward to use, if you want an example:

```
void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter(textFileName.Text);
   //resObj is an object you want to store in resx file
   writer.AddResource("key", resObj);
   writer.Generate();
}
```

That's all.

Comment: It's an object you want to store in the resx file (e. g. a string or an image). You can also omit that line and save an empty resource, I suppose.